# How mean, median and mode changes with change in one element of set.

Tags: statistics

I have N numbers. Let mean of these numbers be A. Mode of these numbers be B.Median be C.

Now if I change one element in these, how will my mean, median and mode change ? Can I calculate it directly? Without doing from scratch.

Comment: This question is an attempt to cheat in a programming competition http://www.codechef.com/TCFS15P/ . "Learner" has posted four questions here today from the same competition.

Answer (score 2):

If your element had the value $a$ and was changed to $b$, the mean changes to $A + (b-a)/n$.

If both $a$ and $b$ are on the *same side* of the median, then the median is unchanged. If not, then you still have the original list sorted from when you calculated the median, and moving one element isn't that hard to take into account.

The mode might change if $a$ was the old mode, or if $b$ becomes the new mode. At least it's easier to check than to go through the whole list again.